# Login with FB webview on android - can't pass "confirmation" step because only "cancel" button is clicked when pressing "confirm"

Tags: javascript, android

I have a code for SSO through FB in Android App, and recently it stopped working.
Below the code:

```
wd.addPromiseChainMethod('continueWithFacebook', function (credentials) {
console.log('select continue with facebook');
return this.waitForElementByXPath(ELEMENTS.CONTINUE_WITH_FB, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
  .click()
  .changeToWebviewContext()
  .waitForElementById(ELEMENTS.FB_WEBVIEW.LOGIN, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
  .click()
  .sendKeys(credentials.email)
  .waitForElementById(ELEMENTS.FB_WEBVIEW.PWD, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
  .click()
  .sendKeys(credentials.password)
  .waitForElementByName(ELEMENTS.FB_WEBVIEW.LOGIN_BTN, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
  .click()
  .waitForElementByXPath(ELEMENTS.FB_WEBVIEW.CONFIRM_BTN, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
  .click()
  .changeToNativeContext();
```

});

This part of code:

```
.waitForElementByXPath(ELEMENTS.FB_WEBVIEW.CONFIRM_BTN, TIMEOUT.MEDIUM, TIMEOUT.POLL)
```

.click()

Is supposed to wait for "Confirm" button:
[image]

But currently:

- waitForElementByXPath causes click on the "Cancel" button ( i tried scenario without .click()) and it also clicked)
- when I change path to confirm BTN to: "Cancel" or "close" - it also press the same "cancel" button
- when I tried to force tap on the localization of "Continue" button - it still clicks on "Cancel" button.

Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution finally, chromedriver wasn't starting, that's why elements weren't located properly